# Mongoose remove nested document not working

Tags: mongoose

My problem is:I didnt find any solution of my problem. My problem is : I have a nested document like this:

Post object is main object and Post object has two embedded object as Like and Comment. This is the javascript schemas codes.

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
             username: String,
             post: String,
             date: {
                   type: Date,
                   default: Date.now
                   },
        likes:[Likes.Schema],
        comments : [Comments.Schema]
});



var LikeSchema = new Schema({
                   username: String,
                   date: {
                         type: Date,
                         default: Date.now
                   }
});

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
            username: String,
            comment: String,
            date: {
                  type: Date,
                  default: Date.now
                  }
});
```

And my test datas like this on mongodb:

```
{
"_id": {"$oid": "54fdbedf7c3da52a065ba71b"},
"post": "Deneme postuı",
"username": "fatihayyildiz",
"comments": [],
"likes": {
    "username": "gurkan",
    "_id": {"$oid": "54fdbf067c3da52a065ba71c"},
    "date": {"$date": "2015-03-09T15:40:54.368Z"}
},
"date": {"$date": "2015-03-09T15:40:15.100Z"},
"__v": 0
}
```

So if I go back to my problem I want to remove this like object from my post object.

```
{
    "username": "gurkan",
    "_id": {"$oid": "54fdbf067c3da52a065ba71c"},
    "date": {"$date": "2015-03-09T15:40:54.368Z"}
}
```

So I tried this solution.As you understand I 'm using mongoose library for database action:

```
    var query = Like.find({ '_id': likeid });
    //console.log(query);
    query.remove(function(){

        //console.log("Deleted");
        res.json({
                status:"Deleted"
        });

    }).exec();
```

This code push to me Deleted and no error but when I check my database it's still there.

Mongoose version is "^3.8.24"

How can I remove this nested object from my Post object ?

Comment: your data looks strange, `likes` is an array on the model but a property on the JSON, is that a typo or part of the error?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question @FelipePereira

Comment: your test data should be `"likes": [ array of likes ]` but is `"likes": { like object }`

Comment: Okey I understand now. So how can I change "like" object like this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here you need to understand. First, if you create a Like object together with a Post object it will only exist there. Example:

```
# js
new Post({
    username: 'test',
    likes: [
        {
            username: test,
        },
    ],
}).save(function(err, post) {
    ...
});

# mongo
db.posts.find()
{ "username" : "test", "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e4"), "likes" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e3"),  "username" : "test" } ] }
db.likes.find()
```

To remove the like object you need to pull the object from post like this:

```
# js
post.likes.pull({_id: '54ff6091933a118f790180e3'});
post.save();

# mongo
db.posts.find()
{ "username" : "test", "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e4"), "likes" : [ ] }
```

If you want the Like to be their own objects you need to create the object first and add it to the post:

```
# js
new Like({
    username: 'test',
}).save(function(err, like) {
    new Post({
        username: 'test',
        likes: [like],
    }).save(function(err, post) {
        ...
    });  
})

# mongo
db.posts.find()
{ "username" : "test", "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e4"), "likes" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e3"),  "username" : "test" } ] }
db.likes.find()
{ "username" : "test", "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e3") }
```

But this doesn't mean that you can simply delete the Like object and it will be removed from post. You still need to pull it.

```
# js
like.remove();

# mongo
db.posts.find()
{ "username" : "test", "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e4"), "likes" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("54ff6091933a118f790180e3"),  "username" : "test" } ] }
db.likes.find()
```

Hope that explained a bit. To have it work seamlessly you should look into having remove hooks on your Like object so whenever an object is removed it will remove the like from a Post.

```
LikeSchema.post('remove', function(like) {
    Post.find({likes: like._id}, function(err, posts) {
        for (var post in posts) {
            post.likes.pull({_id: like._id}).save();
        }
    })
})
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, You write a lot but no ones is working. I tried this : `post.likes.pull({_id: '54ff6091933a118f790180e3'});
post.save(); ` and this:
`LikeSchema.post('remove', function(like) {
    Post.find({likes: like._id}, function(err, posts) {
        for (var post in posts) {
            post.likes.pull({_id: like._id}).save();
        }
    })
}) `

Comment: How do you mean it's not working? You mean you run that code and it's still not removed from mongodb?

Comment: Yes I run these 2 code and still not removed from mongodb

Comment: Works well for me when I tried it. Could you add some console logs to see if anything happens.

Comment: When I run last case of code this error appear:

`TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
   if (!(this instanceof model))
     return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
   Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
 } has no method 'post'
   at router.post.post.post.post.postid (/home/ubuntu/workspace/api/services/PostService.js:64:14) `

Comment: Ok. What happens at row 64 then?

Comment: Line 64 is this code ` LikeSchema.post('remove', function(like) { ` Then you already know whats going from your code. Like model has no method post

Comment: That is right. You are applying it to the mongoose schema right. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post

Comment: Yes but I am creating new Schema(...) at another .js document. Like.js has this Schema implementation and I get that Schema with var  `Like = require('../models/Like/Like'); ` then I am writing Like.post(...bla bla). It give me trouble you think ?

Comment: But Like is the actual schema and not the model? I would move the post remove hook to that file instead. It belongs to the Like implementation.

Comment: Yes it is schema. I tried to do this : ` var likeSchema = new Like();
        likeSchema.post('remove', function(like) { ` . This is not giving me error dont fire this callback function. I waited about 5 mn. to fire it but no. And in mongo db its still not remove document.

Comment: It won't be fired until you remove a Like object.